# Trigger log in on enter key

Tags: javascript, html, authentication, enter

Apologies in advance, I know this has been asked before (I did do the search).

The reason I'm posting is because I need help specifically to my situation as I can't work it out with other examples.

I'm trying to trigger logging in by pressing enter instead of clicking but have had no luck (been searching for hours and hours).

Here is my code behind:
    script>

```
    function loginBtn_Click() {
        doLogin();
    }

    function doLogin() {

        var args = {
            'UserId': document.getElementById('UserId').value,
            'ContactId': document.getElementById('ContactId').value,
            'Password': document.getElementById('Password').value


        };

        var callback = function (data) {
            document.location.href = 'matters.html';
        }

        DoAjaxCall('ws/general.asmx/Login', args, callback);
        }

</script>
```

Here is my HTML:
      
            Please enter your login details

```
        <input id="UserId" type="text" placeholder="Username" /><br />
        <input id="ContactId" type="text" placeholder="Contact Reference" /><br />
        <input id="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password" /><br />
        <div id="loginBtn" class="btn" onclick="loginBtn_Click();" onkeypress="DoAjaxCall;">Log in</div>

        <br /><br />

        <p>Error logging in?</p>
        <p>Contact your liason at Buckles Solicitors LLP directly or alternatively call reception on <b>01733 888888</b>.</p>

    </div>
```

I would appreciate your help.

Thanks in advance,
Rajan

Comment: I am no Javascript expert but, if hitting login and pressing enter do the same thing, why not in `onkeypress` do `onkeypress="doLogin();"`

Comment: If you change your button to be an `input` and `type=submit`, then it should be the default button when pressing the enter key.

Comment: in most cases this will work, however the [spec](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html#submit-button) do not mention anything about 'enter' while focused on a form input. This is non-standard and just so happens to be the case for major browsers. FYI.

Comment: Rick! Worked brilliantly! Thanks! Sometimes it's just that easy.

Comment: @RSKandola You should except his answer... :)

Answer (score 0):

Yep as Rick S mentioned, I just changed it to input type and submit, nothing else and it works perfectly. Added new code in css to reference the input type of submit and it works like a charm!

```
<div id="main"><br /><br />
        <h2 id="logoutStatus">Please enter your login details</h2>

        <input id="UserId" type="text" placeholder="Username" /><br />
        <input id="ContactId" type="text" placeholder="Contact Reference" /><br />
        <input id="Password" type="password" placeholder="Password" /><br />
        <input type=submit value="Log in" onclick="return loginBtn_Click();">

        <!-- Old log in button, works but no on hitting Enter
        <div id="loginBtn" class="btn" onclick="loginBtn_Click();" onkeypress="return loginBtn_Click();">Log in</div>-->

        <br /><br />

        <p>Error logging in?</p>
        <p>Contact your liason at Buckles Solicitors LLP directly or alternatively call reception on <b>01733 888888</b>.</p>

    </div>
```

Thanks guys!